# How can you set a MongoDB write concern at database level that cannot be overridden?

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to prevent clients of a database using any write concern other than majority for a replica set. Is it possible to do this at a database level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to prevent the use of write concerns other than the default. Clients can specify a write concern for each CRUD operation and MongoDB's permission model is not granular enough to prevent this. If you really want to prevent the write-concern being changed by your client, you could create a REST API that wraps most common MongoDB operations, but prevents users from setting the write concern.